# Not persistent HTTPCookieStorage with GroupContainerIdentifier

Tags: swift, uikit, httpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

I set up a `HTTPCookieStorage` like this:

```swift
let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.sharedCookieStorage(forGroupContainerIdentifier: "user100")
storage.cookieAcceptPolicy = .always
let cookieProperties: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] = [.name : "example\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)",
         .value : "value\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)",
            .domain : "www.example\([100,200,300].randomElement()!).com",
         .originURL : "www.example.com",
         .path : "/",
         .version : "0",
         .expires : Date().addingTimeInterval(2629743)
        ]

storage.setCookie(HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)!)
```

I found out that doing the same for `HTTPCookieStorage.shared` actually saves the cookies, this custom `HTTPCookieStorage` is not. How to make it persistent?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my finding, the purpose of `forGroupContainerIdentifier` cookies is to share cookies across your applications. Like in one app you create one group for cookies storage and in another application, you want to access that group so for that purpose you need to choose the right name of a group. You need to create group on app portal developer site and need to add that group in your both application bundle ids. after that, you will be able to use those cookies. For more information please check this thread. [Cookies storage](https://medium.com/@mahithegeek/sharing-cookies-in-ios-nshttpcookiestorage-part-2-ee466c17e96)